# mRNA vaccine and cell mitosis

Tags: coronavirus, vaccination, mrna, mitosis

What happens with the injected mRNA when cells are in the different stages of the mitosis process? Does the mRNA enter the cell and behaves normally throughout the mitosis phases?

Comment: I'd be interested in some reference. What made you think about the relationship of  m-RNA and cell cycle? (This reminds of some current issue: activation of LINE1 (LINE-1) retrotranscriptase, i.e. transcription of viral mRNA to DNA, depending on cell dividing or not).

Answer (score -1):

According to [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7076378/) written by Abishek Wadhwa and his colleagues,  the vaccine mRNA will exert its function independent on active cell division because it is not integrated into the host genome [[1]](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7076378/).

Interestingly, I also found [this paper](https://biomedres.us/fulltexts/BJSTR.MS.ID.005501.php) which indicates that there is a possibility that the mRNA can enter the nucleus during cell division. During the prophase of mitosis, the nuclear membrane is dissolved, allowing mRNA to passively diffuse into and be included within the nucleus later during telophase. In addition, if endogenous reverse transcriptase is present, the mRNA can end up being integrated into the host genome [[2]](https://biomedres.us/fulltexts/BJSTR.MS.ID.005501.php).

Resources:

1. Wadhwa A, Aljabbari A, Lokras A, Foged C, Thakur A. Opportunities and Challenges in the Delivery of mRNA-based Vaccines. Pharmaceutics. 2020;12(2):102. Published 2020 Jan 28. doi:10.3390/pharmaceutics12020102
2. Sousa A, José M.M., Velilla A. Z.mRNA, Nanolipid Particles and PEG: A Triad Never Used in Clinical Vaccines is Going to Be Tested on Hundreds of Millions of People. Biomedical. 2021;34(1):2574. Published 2021 Feb 22. doi:10.26717/BJSTR.2021.34.005501

Comment: Please note that the first of these articles was accepted nine days after submission. This suggests it was not properly reviewed. In addition, the publisher of "Pharmaceutics" is ["MDPI" — a publisher with a history of poor behavior and minimal peer-review](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDPI#Controversies). I would tend to treat articles published in such journals as highly suspect.

Comment: [Predatory journals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predatory_publishing) are a huge problem — you can [learn more](https://mdanderson.libanswers.com/faq/206446) and see lists of [predatory journals](https://predatoryjournals.com/journals/) including the original [Beall's List](https://beallslist.net/).

Comment: The second article, by Sousa et al., was published in the "Biomedical Journal of Scientific & Technical Research" which is not peer reviewed and seems to accept any paper if the fees are paid.  Among the gems it has published are "The Expression of the Proper-Name Effect Reinforces the Disarticulation ofCommunicative Rationality" and "Nietzsche and the Big Health. The Art as Culture’s Therapy".

Comment: @mgkrebbs I can't even hazard a guess at the content of the second paper.

Comment: @tyersome The 1st article was accepted about a month after submission (Received 2019 Dec 28; Accepted 2020 Jan 26), and it's a review. The timing does not seem to be an issue, although the publisher certainly may be.

Comment: @Armand — Interesting, I may of screwed that up, but I wonder if they've changed that info (nine days doesn't fit any of the currently listed publication related intervals) . At any rate this is a suspect journal and is being used to support an answer that makes dubious claims.